# How to implement a GitHub repository of Sample android apps?

Tags: android, github

My objective is to implement a GitHub repository that contains a set of android sample apps.

As a reference of what I want to achieve, see this [link](https://github.com/android/compose-samples).

Note that, each Android app is contained in its directory (a sub-directory of the main directory), and there is no relationship between each Android app (sub-directory).

Comment: Just copy your apps folder and paste to new folder and open in android studio and send to github repository or using git command to upload your folder

Comment: Will I be able to commit and push individual apps (sub-directories), or I will have to do it for the main folder that contains the apps? The idea is to work in Android studio each app at a time, commit and push it, without the necessity of commiting and pushing the folder that contains the app.

Comment: What I`ve done. First of all, at GitHub, I created a repository i.e, the main directory. Then I cloned this repository to create a local copy on my computer. In Android Studio, I created an Android project inside the cloned directory and commited / pushed this project to GitHub (I had to add it to vsc). It works.